# How to set non-random file names on imgur.com

Tags: imgur

How can I set images to have non random file names on imgur.com?

When I upload an image, a random string gets assigned to it.

How would I link to an image like username.imgur.com/meaningful_file_name.jpg instead of username.imgur.com/6dtgw.jpg?

Flickr does a similar thing.  This can't be done for the sake of creating unique file names, as the username can provide that.

Answer (score 9):

1. Upload the image. Get the image URL, such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiaR1.png
2. Add a slash to the direct URL, followed by whatever string you want, such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiaR1.png/Caturday.png
3. ????
4. Profit!

[image]

P.S.: I found this out by myself...

Comment: Cool! This is called creative

Comment: ...it *still* has the randomly generated filename, you're just adding more to it.

Comment: @ashleedawg exactly. how does this solve referencing the filename?

Answer (score -2):

I think your best bet is to sign up (or log in if you already have an account) to Reddit and post your question in the [Imgur subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/imgur) there. MrGrim (the Reddit username of Imgur's creator) regularly checks in there. And even if he doesn't answer, I'm sure the other Redditors subscribing to that subreddit will be able to tell you.